# BlackBerry - is it possible to develop branded applications?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, mobile, branding

I've been asked to look into the development options for BlackBerry. My client wants to build an application that represents their brand. I realize that there are different techniques for doing development and the Java/J2ME approach is probably the most powerful.

Does anyone have experience with building branded applications, or have screenshots of BlackBerry applications that push the envelope in terms of user interface/experience?

I'd also like some feedback on the impact of the techniques in terms of experience. I'm sure there are various drawbacks to approaching an application from the branding angle, but I'd like to highlight these to my client.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maker of PodTrapper (my favorite BlackBerry app), posted a great writeup on his experience here: http://www.versatilemonkey.com/story.html

One interesting thing I learned was that the framework actually makes you rewrite a lot of the display elements from scratch. So, yes, it's pretty easy to brand an app as your own (too easy).

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently developing a blackberry application for my company. It's heavly branded (uses the company logo and colors from our cooperate identity). The blackberry api delivers many methods to display custom content. Personally, I see no problem in it.

Just set up a sample enviroment (it's free) and start developing.